# Unable to fetch Anchor Tags in WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have this piece of code which is supposed to fetch the all the anchor tag and click on it.  Since the link gets open up in new tab there is a getWindowHandle code.  Upon running the code i get "ElementNotVisibleException" error.  I want to know where am i going wrong.

```
public void FetchingAllHomePageLinks() throws Exception
  {
        /* Anchor Tag(a) is a WebElement, hence its stored in the form of list  */
        List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        /* Array of string stores the linkelements size */
        String[] linkTexts = new String[linkElements.size()];

        int i=0;
        //For every webelements consist of linkelements, its text has been stored in linktext
        for(WebElement e : linkElements)
        {
            linkTexts[i]=e.getText();
            i++;
        }

        for(String T : linkTexts)
        {
            if(!T.equals(null) || !T.equals("") || !T.isEmpty())
            {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText(T))).click();
                //Since the link if clicked opens in new tab hence getWindowHandles Code
                String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();   
                  System.out.println("Parent Window ID is : " + parentWindow);

                  Set<String> allWindow = driver.getWindowHandles();

                  int count = allWindow.size();
                  System.out.println("Total Window : " + count);

                  for(String child:allWindow)
                  {
                      if(!parentWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(child))
                      {
                          driver.switchTo().window(child);
                          if(driver.getTitle().contains(errorTitle))
                            {
                                System.out.println("'" + T + "'" + " Is Under Construction");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("'" + T + "'" + " Is working fine");                 
                            }
                          Thread.sleep(3000);
                          driver.close();
                      }
                  }
                  driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
            }
        }
        driver.close();

}
```

Comment: At which line are you exactly stuck? Update the question with the error stack trace. I don't see you performing any _Selenium_ driven actions after you switch to the new TAB.

Comment: I kept this line wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText(T))).click(); because i was facing an error. Switching to the tab is because the link if clicked opens a new window and there it checks if the page is getting displayed or showing 404 Page Error.

Comment: This is the error that gets displayed when i try to run the code:


FAILED: FetchingAllHomePageLinks
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'abc-PC', ip: '192.168.0.100', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: add an Explicit wait  with condition of becoming clickable before the statement you get this error

Comment: @kushal Yes thank u for the suggestion but i have already used just after the if conditions : if(!T.equals(null) || !T.equals("") || !T.isEmpty())
            {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText(T))).click();

Comment: Try one thing replace this wait with "Thread.sleep(5000)" for judt testing purpose, see if that works!

Comment: The anchor may actually be invisible. If you have found a hidden link, the user wouldn't be able to click on it. If you absolutely must check it then try grabbing the `href` attribute instead of clicking, like `driver.get(...until(...presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText(T))).getAttribute("href"))`. Note that this would not be the same as clicking on it as it wouldn't trigger any event handlers or other logic around the click